# interval of convergence of the power series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}x^n$

Tags: real-analysis, power-series

Find the radius of convergence and the interval of convergence of the power series

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty(1+\frac{1}{n})^{n^2}x^n$

My attempt: The root test brings us to

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}|(1+\frac{1}{n})^nx|$,

but I'm not sure where this brings me. Is the ratio test any help?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: What is the limit for $e$?

Comment: $\lim (1+1/n)^n$ is one of the best known limits in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *Note:* Both tests, *[root test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests#Root_test)* as well as *[ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_test)* can be used to analyze the convergence behavior. But, the first one is in this case considerably simpler to use.

We recall the *[validity of the limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_%5C%28mathematical_constant%5C%29#History)*
\begin{align*}
  \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n=e
  \end{align*}

> **Root test:**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\sqrt[n]{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}x^n}\right|
> =|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n}
> =|x|e
> \end{align*}
>
> and we conclude the series is convergent for
>   \begin{align*}
>   |x|<\frac{1}{e}
>   \end{align*}
>   and divergent for $|x|>\frac{1}{e}$.

$$ $$

> **Ratio test:**
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left|\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{(n+1)^2}x^{n+1}}
>     {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}x^n}\right|
> &=|x|
> \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{n^2+2n+1}}
>     {\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^{n^2}}\\
> &=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\left(\frac{n(n+2)}{(n+1)(n+1)}\right)^{n^2}
>     \left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n+1}\\
> &=|x|\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}
>     \underbrace{\frac{1}{\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2+2n}\right)^{n^2}}}_{\longrightarrow \ \  \frac{1}{e}}
>     \underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{2n}}_{\longrightarrow\ \  e^2}
>     \underbrace{\left(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^{1}}_{\longrightarrow \ \  1}\\
> &=|x|e
> \end{align*}
>   and we conclude as above.